# How to reload the UIView after NSXMLParser in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using NSXMLParser to parse some xml data. I am using some delegate method like,

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

This NSXMLParser is in MYAppDelegate.m, Now I want to reload the UI after completing the parsing on Home.m, also I start activity indicator when I request to web service and stop it in didEndElement. But I noticed sometimes found character dosen't get called and My UI freezes. I want to update my UI after parsing is completed. How I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to reload your view in:

*Sent by the parser object to the delegate when it has successfully completed parsing*:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

*Sent by a parser object to its delegate when it encounters a fatal error. When this method is invoked, parsing is stopped*:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

Comment: I tried calling my UI update method in parserDidEndDocument, but I didnt get any strings in foundCharacters and my Home.m gets updated with old data. I want my UI to be responsive after I get the parsed data. How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know architecture of your app so it very hard to give accurate answer. All I can suggest that you should combine that methods and reload data when new data is available

Answer (score 0):

You can create an NSOperation subclass and try to parse XML in that class to avoid UI freezing more info how to achieve this , take a look here [NSOperaion](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)

to redraw UIView   call [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score -1):

When your app's

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

is called then you want to do

```
[self reloadView];
```

or whatever your reload method is.